# How to get each jquery to look for spaces

Tags: jquery, html

I have a slight JQuery issue that I am struggling with. The Codepen I have created is a script where if a tab has no content then it removes the corresponding tab heading. The code below is working great as long as the .tab-content div has no spaces, if a space is inside of that div then the code breaks and the tab re-appears.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="tab-boxes cf">
  <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
    <li class="tab1">
      <a href="#view1">Tab 1</a>
    </li><!--li .tab1-->

    <li class="tab2">
      <a href="#view2">Tab 2</a>
    </li><!--li .tab2-->

    <li class="tab3">
      <a href="#view3">Tab 3</a>
    </li><!--li .tab3-->
  </ul><!--ul .tabs-->

  <div class="tabcontents">
    <div id="view1">
      <div class="tab-content">I am Tab One</div>
    </div><!--#view1-->

    <div id="view2">
      <div class="tab-content">Hello, I am Tab Two</div>              
    </div><!--#view2-->

    <div id="view3">
      <div class="tab-content">    </div>
    </div><!--#view3-->
  </div><!--.tabcontents-->
</div><!--.tab-boxes-->
```

JQuery:

```
var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function(){
  $j('.tab-content').each(function(i){
      if(!$j(this).text().length) $j('.tabs li').eq(i).hide();
  })
});
```

Here is my current Codepen link:

http://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/NqOdrM

Cheers,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.trim()` to remove whitespace from the beginning and ending of a string.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/#str

So I guess you could e.g. do

```
if (! $.trim( $(this).text() ).length )
```

or

```
if (! $(this).text().trim().length )
```

Comment: Cheers Roope. Tried this and it seems to work: var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function(){
  $j('.tab-content').each(function(i){
      if(!$j(this).text().trim().length) $j('.tabs li').eq(i).hide();
  })
});

Comment: @NickElse Okay, great, please accept the answer. Also, is there a reason for using `$j` and not just `$`? You don't need to do that, you know?

Comment: it's for my place of work, it's one of their internal quirks when using JQuery.

Comment: @NickElse Haha, of course, didn't remember that one

Comment: Ended up using your 1st suggestion above and it worked so much better than I could of imagined, especially if rogue <br> tags are being used (working with a CMS can do this). Cheers again buddy!